# Titanium: On The Fly Masked TextField

Tags: titanium, textfield, mask, titanium-alloy

Titanium-Alloy SDK 3.2.1, Android 4.2.2.

Hi there, I would like to know if you have had the need to mask a textfield on the fly.

One project I am working on needs the user to input some formatted numbers (numbers+punctuation). On my best efforts, I've made a example project that makes use of a masked textfield using keypressed events on Android. It's [HERE](https://github.com/ffabreti/OnTheFlyMaskedTextField).

Questions are:

- Should I follow this route?
- Or is there a good module avaiable for this?
- Any generic javascript option available (no DOM)?
- Any    suggestions    or better ideas of how to deal with the
  problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`passwordMask` is a boolean textfield property. If you need to dynamically toggle it, just do so in the controller like

```
if (condition){
 textFieldName.passwordMask = true;
}
```

Comment: Or do so in XML using passwordMask="true" (if you're using Alloy).

Comment: @IvoPereira your suggestion does not meet the requirement for being dynamic. The xml view is static and only used as a template.